# Extracting a substring that starts and ends with a digit

Tags: regex, substring, match

I would like to extract the first substring that starts with a digit and ends with a digit through a regex.

- BLAH **1174** (RE:q) --> should extract 1174
- BLAH **1194** (RE:g)5454 --> should extract 1194
- TITI **1026** (RE: w) 54454 --> should extract 1026
- TOTO **2009-21** --> should extract 2009-21
- TOTO**2009-21** --> should extract 2009-21
- TUTU **2008-15** 2013-12 --> should extract 2008-15

I can match the digits (with [0-9]+) but can't find anyway to handle the full request yet.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: How are you matching the digits?

Comment: Which lang you're running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use capturing group based regex.

```
^\D*(\d\S*\d)
```

or

In C#.

```
@"(?m)(?<=^\D*)\d\S*\d"
```

And get string you want from group index 1.

**OR**

Just disable the global modifier `g`. So that it won't find another match in the same line.

```
\d\S*\d
```

Comment: Thanks. Seems I would have to run 2 regex then? No way to extract the first match only? The last example not working

Comment: if you're on php, you may use this, `^\D*\K\d\S*\d`

Comment: I am using C# actually

Answer (score 1):

We want to look for a digit `/\d/`, then look for as many characters as possible `/.*/`, and then find another digit at the end `/\d/`.

Combining these all together, your regex: `/\d.*\d/`.

If you want to only match words that satisfy this condition use: `\d\w*\d`. The 
`\w*` matches only word characters in between the two digits.

If you want non-word characters too, use `/\d\S*\d/`, which will give you any non-space string starting and ending with a digit.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Though in the last example, would like to take the first digit chain. Anyway to do so?

Comment: I don't understand the question

Comment: In this one: "TUTU 2008-15 2013-12", I would want to extract "2008-15" only, however it extracts "2008-15 2013-12"

Comment: You'd want to look at the "only match words" second part of my answer

Comment: Thanks but word isn't working. It's leaving out non digits while I want those